# Is there a way to make Azure DevOps stages expanded by default?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-multistage-pipeline

I have made a Azure DevOps multistage pipeline in YAML that works fine.

This is snapshot of it.

[image]

By default all stages are collapsed, and I need to click on Expand stage to see all jobs/tasks.

[image]

Here is one of them are Expanded:
[image]

My Question: Is there a way to make all stages UI expanded by default?